# What is the PHP equivalent of this C# encoding code?

Tags: c#, php

I want to turn the following C# code into PHP.

The C# is:

```
byte[] operation = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("getfaqs");
byte[] secret = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Password");

var hmac = newHMACSHA256(secret);
byte[] hash = hmac.ComputeHash(operation);
```

Which I've turned into this:

```
$hash = hash_hmac( "sha256", utf8_encode("getfaqs"), utf8_encode("Password"));
```

Then I have:

```
var apiKey = "ABC-DEF1234";
var authInfo = apiKey + ":" + hash

//base64 encode the authorisation info
var authorisationHeader = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authInfo));
```

Which I think should be:

```
$authInfo = base64_encode($apiKey . ":" . $hash);
```

Or

```
$authInfo = base64_encode(utf8_encode($apiKey . ":" . $hash));
```

But not certain, notice this second encoding uses Encoding.UTF8, not UTF8Encoding.UTF8.

What should the PHP code look like?

Comment: `UTF8Encoding.UTF8` and `Encoding.UTF8` are equivalent. `UTF8Encoding` inherits from `Encoding` so it gains the `UTF8` property as a result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP strings are already (kind of) `byte[]`, php doesn't have any encoding awareness. `utf8_encode` actually turns ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, so it's not needed here.

If those strings are literals in your file, that file just needs to be saved in UTF-8 encoding.

Pass `true` to `hash_hmac` as 4th parameter and remove those `utf8_encode` calls:

```
$hash = hash_hmac( "sha256", "getfaqs", "Password", true );
```

Also, string concatenation operator is `.`, so :

```
$authInfo = base64_encode($apiKey . ":" . $hash);
```

Comment: thanks for catching the typo - corrected. Still not authenticating, but I think your code is fine & we have additional problems

Comment: @jmadsen yes, the `C#` is not complete. Before this line: `var apiKey = "ABC-DEF1234";
var authInfo = apiKey + ":" + hash`, `hash` is still a `byte[]`, so how can it be concatenated to a string?