# How to get System.Text of C# in PHP?

Tags: c#, php, .net

Below is the code of both C# and PHP, I need some help regarding it. I am trying to generate the authenticationKey which is in C# but want the convert in PHP. All is done but I don't know how to implement **[System.Text]** in PHP as there is **hash_hmac()** in PHP but what might be the **$string** in the same function.

**C# Version**

```
var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256();
var buffer = userName + accessKey + timeStamp + originUrl;
var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(buffer));
var authenticationKey = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

**PHP version**

```
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $string, $buffer);
$encoded = base64_encode($hmac);
```

Can anyone help me with that. It will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP and C# HMAC SHA256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419006/php-and-c-sharp-hmac-sha256)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also searching for this and atlast it was just a mistake of 1 small varibale, in the hash_hmac function pass the last value as true, this is will return raw output and when you convert it to base64 it will give the same output as the c# code.

```
$buffer = $userName.$accessKey.$timeStamp.$originUrl;
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $buffer, $tokenSecret, true);
$authenticationKey = base64_encode($hmac);
```

Just in your c# function use the key, as shown in the code below

```
var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256();
hmac.Key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tokenSecret);
```

In my code I have tokenSecret variable in bas64 form.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the hex value, using [unpack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) method:

```
$value = unpack('H*', buffer);
echo $value[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your c# code, you used a randomly generated key. Check the documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256?view=netframework-4.8#constructors

> HMACSHA256()
>
> Initializes a new instance of the HMACSHA256 class with a randomly generated key.
>
> HMACSHA256(Byte[])
>
> Initializes a new instance of the HMACSHA256 class with the specified key data

Now the php documentation in comparison: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php

```
hash_hmac ( string $algo , string $data , string $key [, bool $raw_output = FALSE ] ) : string
```

You see, what you call buffer in php, is actually the key and what you call buffer in c# is the data you hash.

So the`$string` should contain the data to be hashed.

As per the conversion,  you don't need to get bytes in php: [What is the PHP equivalent of this C# encoding code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299779/what-is-the-php-equivalent-of-this-c-sharp-encoding-code)

Comment: If you are saying $string should contain data to be hashed then what will come in $buffer. Actually I am integrating Payliance Payment Integration in my PHP Project and the above code is part of it. Any help regarding this documentation would also help.

Comment: buffer = key
Shared secret key used for generating the HMAC variant of the message digest.